# 2 Bugs on the new reputation page

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, reputation-page

I noticed this, and I figured this was the best way to let ya'll know.

1. The page does not show the correct amount of votes if your answer is accepted and upvoted.
2. The alt text that pops up says "answer was upvoted 0 times" despite how many times the answer was upvoted.

[image]

Comment: Reg #2, I can see it always appears as "upvoted 0 times" when the answer was upvoted more than *once on the same day*, otherwise it just says "answer was upvoted". Seems to be incorrect counting in the first case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The votes is indeed by design, it's an "accept vote" that happens...though if someone has universally better description text I'm all ears!

The tooltip was *supposed* to show `...n times` only when there was more than 1 vote for that row....oops?  This is fixed in the next build!

Comment: How about "actions"? "events"? "changes"?

Comment: Which reminds me, could you pretty please cookie the by post/by time selection?  Getting a bit worn out from constantly having to switch back to time.

Comment: @Hans - In the next build there are 2 options stored, one for your *own* profile, one for all others, so you can view by time (detailed) for yourself and another view for all others, etc...this is how favorites, questions and answers already work.  Also, the popup will not force you to a view, it'll respect your own-profile sort/view there.

Comment: This seems to work well, thanks Nick :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the production SE2.0 database schema, but if it is anything like the data dump (data.stackexchange.com) or what is revealed by the [StackApps API](https://stackapps.com/questions/2/getting-started-with-the-api) then all actions that directly affect rep is a "vote". This would put accepting questions in the same boat as up/down-votes, as well as bounty setup, bounty received, accepting an answer (+2 etc.

All rep changes are grouped (within the same day) by post (question/answer) as a single [x vote] node, with the breakdown only shown when you expand it.

I would say this is by-design, you would be better off tagging it as a request, in which case it may be considered or declined. As a bug, it will earn just [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).